Converting PDFs to Markdown for Higher Quality Embeddings with Langchain.js
I am working on RAG LLM projects with Langchain.js using Node.js. Most of the data I retrieve are PDFs and a bit of JSON.
For higher quality, I would like to convert my PDFs into Markdown before embedding starts. This involves deleting headers and footers, extracting tables and pictures, and converting the text into Markdown so that it is clear to the LLM whether it is body text or an important title.
Example: This is Title and < p >just text
I want to ensure that pictures and tables are clearly identified in Markdown, and that unnecessary elements are removed. I have found some Python libraries that people use for this purpose, but I need something for Node.js. Has anyone experienced with this?
And of course, any other tips for better RAG LLM are also welcome! :)
Already tried "markdown-it" library but not really happy with result. The only thing it does is sometimes adding < p >. (Which is still better than nothing but i want everything to be very clear)
It's not clear :

if this text is Title or Body,
Can't delete Footer Information with this
Can't export Table/Picture etc.

